# Adding <a> tags to wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to customize my disqus link colors which as you may know, inherit the link color from the wordpress theme. The problem is my current theme I think hasnt specified any main color so disqus inherit the default blue link color for all the links. This is my stylesheet: http://goo.gl/p8cA9

Could anyone tell me how I could specify a link color in the style sheet? I'm just beginning to learn css and when I add the `a {color:purple;text-decoration:none}` class it deforms the rest of the sites style.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to be specific, look in the source code of your WP webpage (if you use chrome press f12 and then go to the elements tab, press the magnifying glass and select the A tag you want to style on the webpage).

With:

```
a {
color:purple;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

You are saying that all the a tags should be this color. You need to look where the a is located. 
Example:

```
<div class="content">
  <p class="scribble">
    Lorem ipsum <a href="http://google.com/">google</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

In the example above the way I would style this a tag would be.

```
p.scribble a {
color:purple;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

The "."-in the CSS selector refers to a class. So I am saying I want a tag in the p with class "scribble". Good luck with your adventures.

PS. If you are using chrome and you selected your element successfully you can also see the CSS selector it is responding to now (right window).